# How to add Google Analytics tag to SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, google-analytics, analytics

I would like to include the GA TAG into a SSRS report, but can´t find a way to include it into because the HTML is automatic generated by server. The server installed version is 12.0.5571.0. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Change the templates on the server to include the gtag.js.

Comment: I don´t have access to server templates, my company is very restrictive. Is there another way, maybe directly in Report Builder?

Comment: I’m don’t have enough knowledge about SSRS to point you in the right direction. Have you tried looking in the execution logs? Maybe you find your information there.